# Creating a dropdown from an object with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So, I want to get specific keys with value and push them to new array which will use in ng-repeat, I  spent few days to find some solution...

I have object

```
{"id": 5, "code": "05", "name": "Apple", "item": "907520193", "item2": "3234234234", "item3": "4343232", "item4": "32342342", "item5": "78979" }
```

I want to make dropdown/selectbox in the angular just used only this keys **item, item2, item3, item4, item5** (first item is without number).

Comment: That does not look like an Array

Comment: This is  not an array. It is an object

Comment: Objects are associative arrays. http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/javascript/1441-javascript-data-structures-the-associative-array.html

Comment: @epascarello he wants to take specific keys from that object, stick the values into an array, and use that.

Comment: You edited it but it's still not an array. Now it's invalid. I'm going to go out on a limb and say that you should remove this and look further into the subject or do some revising. You say you studied this for days but your question doesn't show that.

Comment: @BrandonRoberts not really, there are major fundamental differences between the two

Comment: They *would* be associative arrays if they had all the methods that arrays have, like `filter`, `reduce`, etc.  Objects are more associative wannabes.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array

Comment: I suppose we can split hairs.

Comment: I think it doesn't matter if it is an array or object

Comment: This question title should be updated to `Creating a dropdown from an object in AngularJS`.

Comment: @Brian you have enough rep to make that edit.

Comment: @Amy thank you :-). Never tried that. Knowledge++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a more "angular" way. This example will iterate over the keys. In the code, `k` is the key, and `v` is the value. It will start the options at the third property (if the data is scattered, see note below). I've set it to display the key in the drop down, and the value as the value. You can of course just use one or the other, swap them, etc.

I prefer this method over generating an array, as it does not have to complete two iterations (first by pre-processing, then to display).

> If you don't know where the items will begin, you can use this instead: `<option ng-repeat="(k,v) in data" value="{{v}}" ng-if="k.indexOf('item') > -1">{{ k }}</option>`

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []).controller('controller', controller);

function controller($scope) {

  $scope.data = {
    "id": 5,
    "code": "05",
    "name": "Apple",
    "item": "907520193",
    "item2": "3234234234",
    "item3": "4343232",
    "item4": "32342342",
    "item5": "78979"
  };

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.6.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="controller">

  <select name="repeatSelect" id="repeatSelect" ng-model="selected">
    <option ng-repeat="(k,v) in data" value="{{v}}" ng-if="$index >= 3">{{ k }}</option>
  </select>

  <hr /> {{ selected }}

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Glad it worked :). Question was confusing at first. I guess tagging as JavaScript got a bunch of JS specific discussion instead.

Answer (score 4):

Use Object keys, Array filter and map to achieve this,

```js
let obj = { "id": 5, "code": "05", "name": "Apple", "item": "907520193", "item2": "3234234234", "item3": "4343232", "item4": "32342342", "item5": "78979" };
let arr=Object.keys(obj).filter((key)=>key.indexOf('item')>-1).map((key)=>obj[key]);
console.log(arr);
```